# "Invalid key: 0. Please first select a split. For example: `my_dataset_dictionary['train'][0]`. Available splits: ['train']"

Tags: dataset, huggingface-transformers

I tried to use the dataset API loaded with my own data to train the hunggingface model.
This is my code:

```
train_data= datasets.load_dataset('csv', data_files="/gdrive/MyDrive/project/train.csv")

test_data= datasets.load_dataset('csv', data_files="/gdrive/MyDrive/project/test.csv")
```

```
train_data

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['Post', 'Label'],
        num_rows: 174
    })
})
```

But in the trainer, I get this error message.  What happens to my dataset. I do not find any error. Could you help me?  Thank you!

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=test_data
)
trainer.train()
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-3435b262f1ae> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer.train()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/datasets/dataset_dict.py in __getitem__(self, k)
     44             suggested_split = available_suggested_splits[0] if available_suggested_splits else list(self)[0]
     45             raise KeyError(
---> 46                 f"Invalid key: {k}. Please first select a split. For example: "
     47                 f"`my_dataset_dictionary['{suggested_split}'][{k}]`. "
     48                 f"Available splits: {sorted(self)}"

KeyError: "Invalid key: 0. Please first select a split. For example: `my_dataset_dictionary['train'][0]`. Available splits: ['train']"
```

Comment: Did you tried train_dataset=train_data['train'] ?

Comment: it works for train_data. But how to set for test_data? when I run " test_dataset=test_data['test'] " , it show me that I have keyerror:'test'.   Thank you!

Comment: You can quickly check test_data and take the key it contains.

Comment: Excuse me, did you manage to solve it, I also get KeyError: 'Test' and the KeyError above as you

Answer (score 1):

Create your dataset using

```
data_files = {"train": "masked_story_tcs.csv", "test": "masked_story_tcs.csv"}
dataset_name = '/content'
dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name, data_files=data_files)
```

and then in

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=dataset['test']
)
trainer.train()
```

This way it worked for me

Comment: I'm not geting why "train_dataset=dataset['train']," works but not if you had separated out your train and test data earlier like OP did, so you would just do train_dataset=dataset.  For some reason it's this latter method that gives this error as i'm having the same issue.